# SQL query between two tables looking for specific data in second table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I've been asked to get some data from SQL 2008R2 DB.  I have two tables:

- `Employee` table - has lots of data to include a column with either active or inactive marked for employees
- `Punches` table - holds time clock punches with dates, times, etc & a column that says if the punch has been deleted by payroll.

I'm being asked to write a query that will give a list of active employees from table A that have no punches in table B and/or they have only punches that have been marked as deleted.

A left outer join with a null would work great if the deleted punches were actually deleted from the db instead of being marked with a deletion.

Any help would be appreciated
Thx!
~j

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    EMPLOYEE E
JOIN    PUNCHES P
ON      E.EMPID =  P.EMPID
WHERE   E.ACTIVE = 'Y'
AND     (P.PUNCH_TIME IS NULL OR P.DELETED = 'Y')
```

Comment: Hi,
Here I have taken table A as Employee and Table B as Punches.
The column with either active or inactive marked for employees is taken 'ACTIVE' which will have 'Y' or 'N' based
on whether they are active or inactive
In Punches table I have assumed there is a column which states whether the punch is deleted by the payroll dept 
or not (Column = Punches which will take 'Y' or 'N' values). I have also assumed a column Punch_Time which will 
record the punches. I have assumed that both tables have EMPID as common column.
I hope this works for you.